# Change Hostname permanently on Google Cloud Compute - WHM

Tags: google-cloud-platform, centos, google-compute-engine, centos7, hostname

I've had to change hostname on a Google Cloud Compute that is running a WHM instance, but it keeps resetting every now and then and restart.

My /etc/hosts are currently as follow:

```
127.0.0.1               localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1             localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
10.156.0.7 cpanel.server-location-c.c.ascendant-hub-hidden.internal cpanel  # Added by Google
169.254.169.254 metadata.google.internal  # Added by Google
```

My System Information are:
Linux cpanel.xxx.com 3.10.0-1127.10.1.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Jun 3 14:28:03 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

My Old Hostname is something alike:
cpanel.xxx.com

I want my new hostname to become:
brain.xxx.com

Even when I change it from WHM using their Change Hostname feature, it keeps resetting.

Is their a cleaner method then setting a crontab?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you're not able to change a custom hostname after you've created VM instance. Have a look at the documentation [Creating a VM instance with a custom hostname](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/custom-hostname-vm):

> You can create a VM with a custom hostname by specifying any fully
> qualified DNS name.

and at the section [Limitations](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/custom-hostname-vm#limitations):

> **You cannot change a custom hostname after you have created the VM**.

**To change this behavior** you can try to file a [feature request](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#feature_requests) at Google Issue Tracker under this [component](https://b.corp.google.com/issues/new?component=187134&template=1162898).

**UPDATE** In addition, have a look at the documentation [Storing and retrieving instance metadata](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/storing-retrieving-metadata) section [Default metadata keys](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/storing-retrieving-metadata#default):

> Compute Engine defines a set of default metadata entries that provide
> information about your instance or project. Default metadata is always
> defined and set by the server. **You can't manually edit any of these
> metadata pairs.**

and `hostname` is part of the default metadata entries and could not be changed manually.

**UPDATE 2** **As a possible workaround**, you can use a [startup script](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/startupscript) or other solutions to change the hostname every time the system restarts, otherwise it will automatically get re-synced with the metadata server on every reboot. For example, I applied this startup script via [Custom metadata](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/startupscript#startupscriptrunninginstances):

```
Key: startup-script
Value: #! /bin/bash 
       hostname changed-host-name'
```

then restarted VM instance and it works for me:

```
changed-host-name:~$ hostname
changed-host-name
```

Answer (score 0):

These are few ways to change your hostname:

1. One way is to edit `/etc/hostname` directly - just switch file content with your new hostname.
2. The other way is to use `hostnamectl set-hostname <your new hostname>` which change `/etc/hostname` file for you.

But I think your problem is that **Google keeps to overwrite some data not only when you reboot system but also while your VM is running.** Assuming that above solutions, won't solve your issue.

### Solution:

Thankfully Google Cloud Platform allows you to have custom hostname but **you have to define them when creating new virtual instance**. Check out [this](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/custom-hostname-vm) GCP document.